# Поиск по ключу в массиве

Tags: jquery, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость искать в массиве по ключу. Пример как в php я бы сделал

```
$some=array('movie'=>'фильм','music'=>'музыка');
$some['movie'];
```

Как такое можно на jQuery сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var some={'movie':'фильм','music':'музыка'};
some['movie'];
```

**p.s.** прошу прощения не сразу заметил, что нужно jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.extend({movie:'фильм'},{music:'музыка'}).movie;
});
```

Comment: .
     some.movie

Comment: можно и так, сейчас вариант на jquery напишу, а то как то нетрушно получилось )

Comment: На самом деле не можно а **нужно**, JS != php, LOL